# MySQL extract data from csv string and insert into a second table

Tags: mysql

I have a table where one column is a string with element separated with a semicolon. in each row there are up to K elements. An example is in Table1.

I have to extract the values between the semicolon and insert them into a new table where each element will have its column, as in Table2.

My first approach would be to create a routine in Java to do it (the database is already used by a program that I'm writing to do the analysis), but is there a method to do it only in MySQL?
I have found these two examples (1, 2), but my problem is a little different. I was thinking to extract an array of values from the first table and insert it in the second, but I don't know if this is possible.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated,

---

```
Table1
*****************************
* ID * Col1                 *
*****************************
* 1  * abc;def;ghi;lmn;opq  *
* 2  * agf;hdgk;jsud;       *
*    *                      *
* n  * jd;l;qpekd;kdh;      *
*****************************

Table2
*****************************************
* ID * Col1 * Col2 * Col3 *      * ColK *
*****************************************
* 1  * abc  * def  * ghi  *      *      *
* 2  * agf  * hdgk * jsud *      *      *
*    *      *      *      *      *      *
* n  * jd   * l    * qpekd*      *      *
*****************************************
```

1) [Insert data from another table with a loop in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410224/insert-data-from-another-table-with-a-loop-in-mysql)

2) [mysql :: insert into table, data from another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241621/mysql-insert-into-table-data-from-another-table)

---

Unfortunately I had to do the work in Java, I leave the solution if someone will find the same problem. But the question on how to do it in MySQL is still open

```
public void analyse_Logs(Connection as DB_Connection) {
    String MySQL_String, messageString;
    Long nInitial, nFinal, iRow;

    try{ // begin try-catch for Query_Connection
        this.checkConnection();
        Statement MySQL_Statement = DB_Connection.createStatement();

                try { // begin try-finally for Query_Statement
                    MySQL_String = "SELECT message FROM logs";
                    ResultSet MySQL_ResultSet = MySQL_Statement.executeQuery(MySQL_String);
                    try { // begin try-finally for Query_ResultSet

                        iRow = Long.Valueof(0);
                        while (MySQL_ResultSet.next()) {
                            messageString = MySQL_ResultSet.getString("message");   //for each row, extract log message
                            this.logMessageAnalysis(iRow, messageString);           //call log analysis routine
                            iRow = iRow+1;
                        }

                    } finally {
                        try { MySQL_ResultSet.close(); }
                        catch (SQLException ex) { System.out.println("Error - " + ex.toString()); }
                    } // end try-finally for Query_ResultSet

                } finally {
                    try { MySQL_Statement.close(); }
                    catch (SQLException ex) { System.out.println("Error - " + ex.toString()); }
                } // end try finally for Query_Statement

            } catch(SQLException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error - " + ex.toString());
            } // end try-catch for Query_Connection
}

public void logMessageAnalysis(Long iRow, String logMessage, Connection DB_Connection){
    //split string in array
    String inputArray[] = logMessage.split(";");
    String[] outputArray = new String[16];

    outputArray[0] = String.valueOf(iRow);
    for(int i=1; i<inputArray.length; i=i+1){
        if (inputArray[i].length() > 45) {
            inputArray[i] = inputArray[i].substring(0, 45);
        }
        outputArray[i] = inputArray[i];
    }

    try{ // begin try-catch for Query_Connection
        this.checkConnection();
        Statement MySQL_Statement = DB_Connection.createStatement();

        try { // begin try-finally for Query_Statement
            String Query_String = "INSERT INTO logs_2 VALUES ('";

            for (int i=0; i<15; i=i+1) {
                Query_String = Query_String + outputArray[i] + "','";
            }

            Query_String = Query_String + outputArray[15] + "')";

            MySQL_Statement.executeUpdate(Query_String);
        } finally {
            try { MySQL_Statement.close(); }
            catch (SQLException ex) { System.out.println("Error - " + ex.toString()); }
        } // end try finally for Query_Statement

    } catch(SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error - " + ex.toString());
    } // end try-catch for Query_Connection

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (ID, col1, col2, col3, col4)
  SELECT 
    t1.id
    , substring_index(t1.col1,';',1)
    , substring_index(t1.col1,';',2)
    , substring_index(t1.col1,';',3)
    , substring_index(t1.col1,';',4)
   FROM table1 t1
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index