# Insert other values when using Insert Ignore

Tags: mysql

I got my answer from [Bill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7410336/3581788). But how do I insert other default values not found on the loop select?

I'm doing this which works:

```sql
SET @createdAt = STR_TO_DATE(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');

INSERT IGNORE INTO fancy_table (userId, content, createdAt)

-- Values
SELECT
  userId,
  content,
  -- I faked this
  REPLACE(some_random_col, 'sometimes-value-does-not-match', @createdAt) as createdAt
FROM users
WHERE foo = 'bar';
```

What if I want to update more columns of `fancy_table`, how to do that? The "fake" `REPLACE` column is wrong to me.

**EDIT:**

How can I achieve something like this:

```sql
SET @createdAt = STR_TO_DATE(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');

INSERT IGNORE INTO fancy_table (userId, content, createdAt, etc...)

VALUES (
  (SELECT
    userId,
    content
  FROM users
  WHERE foo = 'bar';),

  @createdAt,

  etc...
)
```

Comment: That does not show an example using `SELECT`

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate link contains a link to the documentation where there are examples with SELECT.

Comment: yes but Im not experience ant duplication here so `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` would not work in my case. Strange it's marked as duplicate. Ill read the docs instead.

Comment: If the duplicate link does not apply to your requirement then edit your question and explain better what you want. As it is currently phrased it looks like you want to insert new rows in the table, but if a row already exists update a column in the existing row.

Comment: Not sure how to put it. I need to insert default values for specific cols for `fancy_table`. Not sure if that goes before the select or after the select. The select does not contain the value I want for the other columns of `fancy_table` ie `created_at`, `updated_at` etc.

Comment: Fine, you clarified what you want with the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@createdAt` directly in the `SELECT` statement:

```
SET @createdAt = STR_TO_DATE(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');

INSERT IGNORE INTO fancy_table (userId, content, createdAt)
SELECT
  userId,
  content,
  @createdAt
FROM users
WHERE foo = 'bar';
```

but, `@createdAt` , is actually the current timestamp which you can get with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `NOW()`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO fancy_table (userId, content, createdAt)
SELECT
  userId,
  content,
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM users
WHERE foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: I actually thought the columns of both tables should match! You live and learn at the same time. Thanks!